# Replacing style attribute of a html element bu class

Tags: javascript, html, styles

I want to replace the style attribute of element.

```
<a class="label-anchor" href="link"><span class="label" style="border-color:#color; color:#color;"></span></a>
```

i want that the **color** attribute get replaced by **background** with same color using js.
Please help...

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('label');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.background = elements[i].style.color;
    elements[i].style.color = null;  
}
```

Comment: there are many elements with same class on the page. the script you have given is working only for one. can it be done for all elements

Comment: @hdd i updated my code to change for all elements in that class

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelector to get the element by its class.

```
const element = document.querySelector('.label');
element.style.removeProperty('color');
element.style.backgroundColor = 'what you want';
```